# do_upload and move_uploaded_file

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm lapiz new to codeigniter and some functions in php 
I'm here to ask again something that's bothering me in uploading files

I tried searching for `do_upload` vs `move_uploaded_file` but I didn't get a good response or clear explanation.

What's the difference between **"do_upload"** from **"move_uploaded_file"** when it comes in uploading files using *php*?

I've been using ***move_uploaded_file*** mostly since I'm used in programming *native PHP*, but I saw in a **tuts**(tutorial)of *codeigniter* the term **"do_upload"** this is new to my eyes and ears so maybe someone can explain it briefly?

Comment: I suppose `move_uploaded_file` is a __core__ php function, `do_upload` is a codeigniter helper.

Comment: I haven't looked the source for it but I imagine its a wrapper for `move_uploaded_file`

Comment: As the [manual](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/file_uploading.html) explains it, `do_upload()` is a method on CodeIgniters Upload helper class.

Comment: All of your answers helped. Thanks :) Sorry if it was a simple question yet I'm unable to grasp it rlqk...

Comment: Yep like I though its a wrapper, on line 568 is this `if ( ! @move_uploaded_file($this->file_temp, $this->upload_path.$this->file_name))` at least in my copy of it.

Answer (score 0):

Actually `move_uploaded_file` is a core PHP function that helps you to upload files.

And there is Codeigniter's file upload library's method `do_upload` which also helps you to upload files.

When you are using Codeigniter and you want more than just uploading the file (like you want the file type restrictions, size restriction, maintain uploaded file renaming etc.) with ease then Codigniter's `do_upload` method (i mean Upload library) will be more handy.

You can see the documentation to know more about Codeigniter's upload library.

https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/file_uploading.html#the-controller